# Create process and anonymous pipe

Tags: c, winapi, pipeline, createprocess

UPDATE Question: So I have been able to create the process and get the programs to compiled. However, I run into a new problem. When I try to pipe the Source program into the Filter program. It doesn't seem to feed in any input for the sink program. There are no error message. I have also test all of my standalone program using the pipe operator in Windows' cmd.

I'm trying to do this small project to learn about anonymous pipe and create process. I created 3 small standalone programs called Source, Filter, and Sink. These 3 are already compiled and run fine. Here's the descriptions for the 3 standalone programs.

Source:  obtains a source text-file filename from its commandline, opens the file,and reads and copies the file contents one character at a time directly to standard output(stdout). When the file has been copied, Source terminates (closing all of its open file handles).

Filter program does not utilize any filename commandline parameters. Instead, Filter reads a text file from standard input (stdin) and writes to standard output (stdout) a copy of the input with all upper-case letters converted to lower-case. Filter specifically must be designed to read one character, convert it, output it, and then loop until the incoming data is finished.

Sink program obtains a destination text-file filename from its commandline, opens the file for writing, and then reads characters one at a time from the standard input file (stdin) and writes each incoming character directly to the destination sink file.

Next I'm driving a main driver program separately that creates 2 pipes and spawn 3 independent child with inputs and outputs configured to carry out the indicated concurrent execution and dataflow. Something like this:

- *srcfile -> Source -> pipe1 -> Filter -> Pipe2 -> Sink -> destfile*

The driver program will requires 2 command line parameters:

- `C:\> Driver.exe srcfile destfile`

where srcfile is an existing data text-file, and destfile is the filename of a new destination file that is to be created by the Sink application.

Here's my code for the driver program. It's not finished yet. But I encountered a hiccup when trying to create a process for the Source program.

UPDATED CODE:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define DELAY_A_WHILE() {volatile long j; for(j = 1; j< 10000; j++) ; } 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hPipeRead, hPipeWrite, hPipeRead2, hPipeWrite2;
    STARTUPINFO StartupInfoSource;
    STARTUPINFO StartupInfoFilter;
    STARTUPINFO StartupInfoSink;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcInfoSource;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcInfoFilter;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcInfoSink;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES PipeAttributes;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES PipeAttributes2;
    char cmdline[200];

    PipeAttributes.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    PipeAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;     //ignore
    PipeAttributes.bInheritHandle = TRUE;           //child can inherit

    //Create first pipe
    if (!CreatePipe(&hPipeRead, &hPipeWrite, &PipeAttributes, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    sprintf_s(cmdline, 200, "Source.exe %s", argv[1]);
    printf("Create process: %s\n", cmdline);

    GetStartupInfo(&StartupInfoSource);
    StartupInfoSource.dwFlags = StartupInfoSource.dwFlags | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;


    //Mapping
    StartupInfoSource.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    StartupInfoSource.hStdOutput = hPipeWrite;
    StartupInfoSource.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

    if (!CreateProcess(
        NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL,
        TRUE,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL,
        &StartupInfoSource,
        &ProcInfoSource))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating child process: %d",GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    CloseHandle(hPipeWrite);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfoSource.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfoSource.hThread);

    PipeAttributes2.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    PipeAttributes2.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;        //ignore
    PipeAttributes2.bInheritHandle = TRUE;          //child can inherit
    //Create Second Pipe
    if (!CreatePipe(&hPipeRead2, &hPipeWrite2, &PipeAttributes2, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    } 

    GetStartupInfo(&StartupInfoFilter);
    StartupInfoFilter.dwFlags = StartupInfoFilter.dwFlags | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    //Mapping
    StartupInfoFilter.hStdInput = hPipeRead;
    StartupInfoFilter.hStdOutput = hPipeWrite2;
    StartupInfoFilter.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

    sprintf_s(cmdline, 200, "Filter.exe");
    printf("Create process: %s\n", cmdline);

    //Filter
    GetStartupInfo(&StartupInfoFilter);
    if (!CreateProcess(
        NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL,
        TRUE,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL,
        &StartupInfoFilter,
        &ProcInfoFilter))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating child process: %d", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
//  int exitStatus;
    //  GetExitCodeProcess(ProcInfoFilter.hProcess, &exitStatus);
    CloseHandle(hPipeRead);
    CloseHandle(hPipeWrite2);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfoFilter.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfoFilter.hThread);


    GetStartupInfo(&StartupInfoSink);
    StartupInfoSink.dwFlags = StartupInfoSink.dwFlags | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;



    //Mapping
    StartupInfoSink.hStdInput = hPipeRead2;
    StartupInfoSink.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    StartupInfoSink.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

    sprintf_s(cmdline, 200, "Sink.exe %s", argv[2]);
    printf("Create process: %s\n", cmdline);

    GetStartupInfo(&StartupInfoSink);
    if (!CreateProcess(
        NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL,
        TRUE,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL,
        &StartupInfoSink,
        &ProcInfoSink))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating child process: %d", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    CloseHandle(hPipeRead2);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfoSink.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfoSink.hThread);


    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles fine. However, when it try to creates the Process, it always fails and exits. The `cmdline` value when it parse in is "Source.exe test.txt", which is exactly what I used to execute my standalone Source program. Can someone explain why my `CreateProcess` fail? Is it because I parse in the wrong parameter?

Comment: So you're saying `CreateProcess` fails? Then you should look into the error code returned by `GetLastError`. BTW, is it correct that you pass the `STARTUPINFO` of the calling process? Is this to pass the handles to stdin and stdout?

Comment: When I try debugging, the program always execute the chunk of code inside that if(!CreateProcess()) which is to print the error when it fails to create and exit the program.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I can see here is the possibility that Source.exe app is not located in the same directory where Driver.exe is located. I tried your code and it was the only case when CreateProcess failed.

Comment: My source.exe is in the same folder as the Driver.c file. Is it the correct place for it to be in?

Comment: Nope. Your binary usually placed to Release or Debug folder (depending on which build config you are using). If you created your project with an option "Create directory for solution" turned on, then you'll see 2 different Release and 2 different Debug folders. You need the one located at upper layers of your directory structure. Anyway, just try to find exact location of your driver.exe file and put source.exe to this folder.

Comment: Can you then provide error code from GetLastError()?

Comment: So i tried fprintf(stderr, "Error creating child process: %d",GetLastError()); and it returned that value 2

Comment: error code 2 = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Are you sure that source.exe is in the same folder as driver.exe? You can also hardcode the full path to source.exe, but in that case take a look first at how it should be formatted on [MSDN CreateProcess page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I have figure out why.

Answer (score -1):

I have figure out why. My project's property was using the Unicode character set. When I switch to Multi-byte character set it works fine.

Comment: That is demonstrably not tire. The code in the question would not have compiled. This is what happens when you lost made up fake code. Shame on you. Switching to multi byte is the wrong way to go. It's 2016. Use Unicode already!

Comment: My code in the question does compiled. I looked up on some other questions here on stackoverflow that said Unicode character set is poorly supported in Win32 console and can't be displayed properly so it is best to avoid. So do you have any suggestion to do it in Unicode character set?

Comment: If that code compiles then Unicode is not defined. Unicode is supported by windows console.